# Google static maps custom marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

This is probably quite simple, but I am struggling to work it out. I am trying to place a custom marker using `lat/lng`

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&scale=2&markers=icon:http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_texts_big&chld=bb%7Cffffff%7C000000%7CPL1+2|50.367285472963,-4.138801595&center=50.367285472963,-4.138801595&zoom=10`

but it does not show the marker - what am I missing?

The marker works:

`http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_texts_big&chld=bb%7Cffffff%7C000000%7CPL1+2`

As does the map with a default marker

`markers=color:red|50.367285472963,-4.138801595&center=50.367285472963,-4.138801595&zoom=10`

Comment: There are issues with the encoding of | and & , but basically you can't use this marker, because it's too large(the max-number of pixels is 4096, but the linked marker has 5133 pixels)

Comment: Thank you very much - there were indeed two problems, built my own custom image maker to solve both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using custom markers, the `icon:` parameter should be URL-encoded.

As your icon is from a deprecated API as stated at the [Dynamic Icons Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons), I will use another custom image as big as possible, that is, as stated by [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) and the [Google Static Maps Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons)

> Icons are limited to sizes of 4096 pixels (64x64 for square images)

Consider my initial marker  (a Catalonian tradition in Nativity manger)  :
https://png.icons8.com/ios/40/000000/full-of-shit.png
[image: man pooping]

I suggest also to shorten it with goo.gl and then URL encode it (could be done online at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) resulting in: `https%3A%2F%2Fpng.icons8.com%2Fios%2F40%2F000000%2Ffull-of-shit.png`, so the final request should look like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&scale=2&markers=icon:shortenedURL-Encoded|50.367285472963,-4.138801595&center=50.367285472963,-4.138801595&zoom=10`

As StackOverflow "suggests" to avoid shorteners, here is the version without shortener:

[image]

Comment: Your image has an error now, you might wanna update your answer

Comment: now it's updated with more fun (I don't mean to poop on Plymouth, it's just a joke, please don't feel attacked in any way as it is a random place chosen)

Comment: My Great Grandfather founded Plymouth how dare you

Comment: well, he also pooped sometimes in Plymouth, didn't he?